# Связанные списки, сложение цифр

Tags: java

На leetcode.com есть задачка на сложение чисел в связанных списках. Посмотрел решение данной задачи и у меня возник вопрос.
Текст задачи:

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative
> integers. 
> The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their
> nodes contain a single digit. 
> Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list. 
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading
> zero, except the number 0 itself.

> Example: 
> Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
> Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8 Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.

Решение:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    ListNode dummyHead = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode p = l1, q = l2, curr = dummyHead;
    int carry = 0;
    while (p != null || q != null) {
        int x = (p != null) ? p.val : 0;
        int y = (q != null) ? q.val : 0;
        int sum = carry + x + y;
        carry = sum / 10;
        curr.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
        curr = curr.next;
        if (p != null) p = p.next;
        if (q != null) q = q.next;
    }
    if (carry > 0) {
        curr.next = new ListNode(carry);
    }
    return dummyHead.next;
      }
    }
}
```

Сам вопрос:
Зачем мы создаем дополнительные переменные и присваиваем им ссылки на связанный список?

```
 ListNode p = l1, q = l2, curr = dummyHead;
```

Ведь мы можем обращаться к next и через переменную l1 и l2. Но в таком случае код работать не будет:

```
ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    ListNode dummyHead = new ListNode(0);
            int carry = 0;
            while (l1 != null || l2 != null) {
                int x = (l1 != null) ? l1.val : 0;
                int y = (l2 != null) ? l2.val : 0;
                int sum = carry + x + y;
                carry = sum / 10;
                dummyHead.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
                dummyHead = dummyHead.next;
                if (l1 != null) l1 = l1.next;
                if (l2 != null) l2 = l2.next;
            }
            if (carry > 0) {
                dummyHead.next = new ListNode(carry);
            }
            return dummyHead.next;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без `p` и `q` вполне можно обойтись. А без `curr` обойтись нельзя.
`dummyHead` указывает на начало списка, и именно его `next` мы возвращаем. А `curr` указывает на конец списка, на то место, куда мы добавляем очередную цифру результата.